# What is RequireQualifiedAccess attribute?

Tags: .net, f#

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.requirequalifiedaccessattribute-class-%5Bfsharp%5D):

> This attribute is used to indicate that references to the elements of a module, record or union type require explicit qualified access.

What is an explicit qualified access? What is an implicit access?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operator behaviour of F# lists, arrays, and sequences is manually mirrored between modules so that you can work with these structures in a consistent way. The implementations are different.

if you'd prefer to work in an implicit style, it's easy to set this up. Like if you are working predominantly with Lists, you could do this:

```
let inline map = List.map

etc.
```

Perhaps in the future, the kind of module will be inferred from the context (ie. we're working with a list, so obviously *map* refers to *List.map*). Ultimately, this is a language design question. What should the sensible default be? Defaults always creep into the broader code bases. On average, is this default more useful to programmers? Hence the RequireQualifiedAccess flag. Someone decided that this was the sensible way to do it. What's idiomatic? Does this still make sense?

The documentation you quote is not strictly true. The below is all *implicit* (I don't need to use a fully qualified explicit DicriminatedUnion.Case1, for example):

```
type DiscriminatedUnion = 
  | Case1
  | Case2
  | Case3

let f x =
  match x with
  | Case1 -> "case1"
  | Case2 -> "case2"
  | Case3 -> "case3"

f Case1
```

Excerpt from the book Expert F#

*Some functional languages, such as Haskell, allow you to implicitly pass dictionaries of operations
through an extension to type inference known as type classes. At the time of writing, this isn’t supported
by F#, but the designers of F# have stated that they expect a future version of the language to support
this. Either way, explicitly passing dictionaries of operations is common in all functional programming
and is an important technique to master.*

Comment: This was always true for DU's (that you didn't need to qualify case labels).

Comment: @scrwtp: true. Thanks for reminding me. Something is behaving much nicer in the recent versions of the Roselyn-ified fsc/fsi/vs tooling, that I haven't quite put my finger on yet. I'll edit the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I heard that future F# would have `[<Trait>]` and `[<Witness>]` copied from Haskell, could we use `map` instead of `List.map` then?

Comment: @MiP: see the excerpt I added above. In short, I don't know. At the moment, a lot of moves seem to be toward robustness + stability over target environments. A promising community led performance based overhaul of how Sequences work suggest that it is possible, though.

Answer (score 23):

Maybe a concrete example would help.

The `List` module has this attribute. This means you're not allowed to open the module:

```
open List // compile error!

map id [1;2]
```

Instead, you must do this:

```
List.map id [1;2]
```

Answer (score 16):

From [The About F# Page](http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/#-consider-using-the-requirequalifiedaccess--and-autoopen-attributes--for-ease-of-use-and-long-term-maintainability-of-the-library-in-common-situations)

> Adding the `[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]` attribute to a module indicates that the module may not be opened and that references to the elements of the module require explicit qualified access. For example, the Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List module has this attribute.
>
> This is useful when functions and values in the module have names that are likely to conflict with names in other modules and requiring qualified access can greatly increase the long-term maintainability and evolvability of a library: functions can be added to the module without breaking source compatibility.